# Codeigniter URL for navigation

Tags: codeigniter, url, view

I can't figure out how to do the url links.

Basically I have my navigation bar, and I don't know which CodeIgniter URL code to use and how to implement it.

Is what I'm doing here right?:

```
<?php $this->load->helper('url'); ?>
<li><a href=" <?php echo site_url("views/about.html"); ?>">About Us</a></li>
```

I tried to do an anchor like this, but when I load the page it just turns up blank:

```
<?php echo anchor('views/about.html', 'About Us', title='About Us'); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your loading the helper within the view which is a bad idea. perhaps auto-load the URL helper in your config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to make links:

CodeIgniter helper style:

```
<?php echo anchor('about', 'About us', 'title="About us link"'); ?>
```

More common HTML with URL echo:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('about');?>" title="About us link">About us</a>
```

Both will output:

```
<a href="http://your_url/about" title="About us link">About us</a>
```

Though if I understand what you are trying to achieve, your mistake is elsewhere.

1. You don't include the `views` part, as your URL should point to the controller, not a view. The only case is if you have a controller named `views`.
2. CodeIgniter is set up so that it doesn't include file extensions like `.html` in URL's by default. It does if you've set them up in your `config` file in `$config['url_suffix'] = '';`, which is null by default.

See if you've made any of these mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

That is another way on how you do the URL if you are using the URL helper in CI. You should try this, make the `base_url()` as the value for `href`. Try this,

`<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/views/aboutus.html">About Us</a>`

Comment: This is absolutely not correct. 1. You should use `site_url()` for links. 2. You should put the segments in parentheses like `base_url('views/about');`

Comment: @Vlakarados, how come it's not correct when it works for me. I simply concatenated `views/about.html` right after I echoed `base_url()`.

Comment: Not everything that works is made right. You will kill yourself when you will want to implement things like `i18n` to your project. I'm not saying this for no reason, I had been doing this like you posted in the beginning, now I can assure you, it can cause so much problems, that you will need to edit every link you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

```
<a href=" <?php echo site_url()."views/about.html"; ?>">About Us</a>
```

or you can give like

```
<a href=" <?php echo site_url(views/about); ?>">About Us</a>
```

and in the "about" function you put

```
$this->load->view('about');
```

but i think the firstone will works for you fine.